# How can I Initiate a TextView item from a menu xml in a Main Activity in android studio

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I'm trying to have the users email which is a textview for that menu show up on the menu in a main activity but I have no clue how to have it instantiated [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAuMb.png)in the main activity java file

```
package com.example.mymycology;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FirebaseAuth auth;
TextView textView;
FirebaseUser user;



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.logout_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Logout:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        textView = findViewById(R.id.user_details);
        
        if (user == null) {
            Intent intent  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else{
            textView.setText(user.getEmail());
        }

        }
    }
```

User details is the ID for that Text in the menu the error is where i try to set the textview to that id

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: You need to add the error you're getting to your question and also add your xml file.